# How to get min and max value from a group array in Groovy

Tags: arrays, groovy, max, min

I'm fairly new to Groovy and I don't know where to begin with this problem.
I have a xml file that contains multiple entries with rid, id and a date.
I've managed to get the elements into an array and I would like to extract rid, min date and max date grouped by each rid. If there is only one entry in the group, min and max date would be the same.

```
Data:
1,1234,2022010101;
2,1235,2022020202;
2,1236,2022030303;

Preferred output:
1,2022010101,2022010101;
2,2022020202,2022030303;
```

Comment: You need just 3 methods. groupBy, min, and max. All here  http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#groupBy(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: You could actually get by with just `groupBy` and `sort`, then use the `0` and `-1` indices as max and min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def dataLines = [
    [1,1234,2022010101],
    [2,1235,2022020202],
    [2,1236,2022030303]
]

def output = dataLines.groupBy { it[0] }.collect { rid, lines ->
    def sorted = lines.sort{ it[2] }
    [ rid , sorted[0][2], sorted[-1][2] ]
}

output.each { println it }
```